# Detect and cut objects from drawing image into section?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, histogram

[image]

What is the best way for detect and cut the objects in drawings like this drawing?

I have just need to separate the drawing into sections.
The programming language is not matter.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you gonna define **objects** ?

Comment: Please edit your question with any code you have written to try solve your problem which (presumably) doesn't work, and show its input/output. Make this a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you haven't written any code then this is off-topic for StackOverflow which is not a code-writing service https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using DBScan algoritem